# Producing non breaking content with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to keep the field and the icon (question mark) at the same line at any time, even if the width is reduced. (preferably using CSS)

I tried various options such as `white-space: nowrap`, putting them in the same `<div/>`, but no success.

[image]

**EDIT**

My HTML markup is similar to the following:

```
<ul data-role="listview" >
            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <div>
                    <label for="name">*Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                    <img src="help.png" title="title" alt="help"/>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I am using HTML5 with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Can we see your HTML? Better yet, could you either supply a working link or fiddle?

Comment: What the hell is `<div/>`? ;)

Comment: Without seeing any code I would suggest something like floating both items and they should then stick together.

Comment: its not only HTML that we need, Maby post your CSS or make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I updated my post with MTML code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`white-space: nowrap` has no effect on elements, it just tells the browser not to split plain text nodes.

To achieve what you want, you need to make the `div` wrapping everything wide enough to display everything in a single line. In the general case, this isn't simple to achieve without JavaScript because CSS has only rudimentary support for aligning several elements.

Solutions:

1. Make the `div` so wide that it will always be able to contain the three elements. This is hard because of the label and impossible if you want the input field to grow (= use all available space).
2. Give the `div` a right margin which is wide enough to contain the image and then position it absolutely in the empty space. Drawback: It will be hard to align the image vertically.
3. The solution that works perfectly but no one wants to hear: Use a table because table rows do what you want / need.

Answer (score 1):

You could try several things actually. The most ugly version is the table. Its also the most easiest one. 
it would look something like this.

```
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td><label for="name">*Email</label></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
             <td><img src="help.png" title="title" alt="help"/></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
```

Also you could try using the propperty inline-block in your css in the questionmark style propperties. It forces the questionmark to stay on the same line as previous element.

```
display: inline-block;
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: The table would also fix actually your floating text (*email) there. else i would apply a vertical allign to your label there.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty, but what happens when you use a non-breaking space?

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"
/>&nbsp;<img src="help.png" title="title" alt="help"/>
```

Note that I moved the closing bracket to the next line to try to keep some sort of order to the code. Pretty ugly still though.

The benefit is that it is "semantic" in that you're instructing the browser that those two pieces of inline content belong together.